# How to push Procfile to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I need to push my Procfile to Heroku but I get this error :

"Heroku push rejected, Procfile is not supported on the Bamboo stack"

I'm running with Rails 3.0.9.

Comment: Procfile stuff is only on the Cedar stack

Comment: Ok so that means I have to create a new app with the cedar stack I guess. Thanks!

Comment: You can change your stack without creating a new app (at least you can for ruby 1.87 -> ruby 1.9.2)

Comment: @Hock Not the case when upgrading to Cedar, you have to create a new app...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in the comments, Procfile only works with Cedar stack on Heroku